# Getting column names from ado.net entity model

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

How do you get the column names from a db?

Currently, I'm interacting with the db through linq-sql using an ado.net entity model. I've searched through StackOverflow and I got a few helpful posts but nothing I've tried has worked.

Like take this post:

[How do I return the column names of a LINQ entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879056/how-do-i-return-the-column-names-of-a-linq-entity)

I tried the responses from Conrad Frix but they didn't work. I'm not exactly sure what he means by a 'Datacontext' anyway. Is that Entity?

```
    AttributeMappingSource mappping = new System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributeMappingSource();
    var model = mappping.GetModel(typeof (AdoModelEntities));
    var table = model.GetTable(typeof (TableName));

    var qFields= from fields in table.RowType.DataMembers
            where fields.IsPersistent == true
            select fields;

    foreach (var field in qFields)
        Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
```

This doesn't work because table is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```
Object LinqObject = Activator.CreateInstance(tableName, null);

//For each field in the database (or property in Linq object)
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in LinqObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{     
     String name = pi.Name;
}
```

LinqObject would be the table object you are trying to get names on.  It doesn't matter how you create it.  That's a way to create it if you just have the string name.

Assuming your .dbml had a table named "Order" it would work just as well to do:

```
Object LinqObject = new Order();
```

You don't have to declare the reference to the table object as an Object either obviously.

Comment: I was able to get it working by changing a few things slightly. TableObject LinqObject = new TableObject();

Comment: I was actually changing that while you were making your comment in case it was confusing.  Thanks.